# How to set the base url in drupal

Tags: drupal, base-url

Where I can set the base url for drupal site. Currently when I go to the site in my localhost, it redirects to the original site. Please help me.

I have tried setting the $base_url in the sites/default/settings.php

Here is  the portion where I set the base url

```
/**
 * Base URL (optional).
 *
 * If you are experiencing issues with different site domains,
 * uncomment the Base URL statement below (remove the leading hash sign)
 * and fill in the URL to your Drupal installation.
 *
 * You might also want to force users to use a given domain.
 * See the .htaccess file for more information.
 *
 * Examples:
 *   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';
 *   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com:8888';
 *   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com/drupal';
 *   $base_url = 'https://www.example.com:8888/drupal';
 *
 * It is not allowed to have a trailing slash; Drupal will add it
 * for you.
 */
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
$base_url = 'http://localhost/mysite';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you don't need to set base_url,
you simply have to **clear drupal cache**.

Comment: More specifically "A PHP file to clear caches and rebuild the routing tables" section worked for me!!!

Answer (score 3):

settings.php

```
$base_url = 'http://baseurl.com';
```

EDIT
You edited as I posted this. Can you paste the portion of your `settings.php` file where you're setting it? Are you sure there's no other `$base_url` set elsewhere in `settings.php`?

Comment: Hi David, initially it was not set in the settings.php I have pasted the code in my question

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can you explain a bit more? How do you know it's not set? What's causing you problems?

Comment: I havn't faced an issue like this before. I have downloaded the contents from the server to my localhost and exported the database. set the database in the settings.php After doing this I have tried to access the site in my localhost. But it redirects to the original site. So I have finally set the base url variable in settings,ph which is optional. Is there any settings in the database. For example in wordpress, we have to change the home and site url in  the database to access the website.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem like this after restoring database from my remote server to my localhost, turns out it was being caused by "mobile tools" which hijacks the redirection of my site whenever it is installed. disabling it before backing up or exporting the database solved the problem. Just posting in case someone ran into this hiccup.