# Copying Drupal from remove server to localhost

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've copied a Drupal site from a live production server over to my `localhost` and I was able to set up the database with the information provided by the `settings.php` file however I cannot seem to go to any page other than the home page.

I keep getting an error saying the requested URL `/production.url/somepage` was not found on this server.

Now I'm guessing that the issue is due to the fact that Drupal is trying to serve up the production URL and not my localhost URL. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you [changed your `$base_url` setting](https://drupal.org/comment/94757#comment-94757)? This will affect the links generated by Drupal. You may also have to [clear your cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5879870/354577).

Comment: I just tried changing it and nothing has changed. Also I cannot clear the cache because I cannot login because of said error.

Comment: @jasonayer, if you manually change `/production.url/somepage` in your browser to `/somepage` does the page load?

Comment: Negative. I tried changing it to my localhost url and it still won't load.

Comment: @jasonayer, have you tried clearing your cache with `drush cc all`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the localhost site is inside a subdirectory and the remote server installation was on the root dir, or a differently named dir.

Go to your .htaccess file on your localhost Drupal installation and look for the line that says `# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory...` and replace the `RewriteBase /drupal` path for the correct subdir name you're using inside your localhost folder.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: I've tried that but I still keep getting an error from Apache saying that any page I go to past the homepage cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush)? You can do most system operations from drush, like clear cache and run update. Clear cache with this command.

```
drush cache clear
```

Also, if the htaccess file has been modified and is causing issues, do a simple debug step, copy it out and replace it with an unmodified file from the version for your drupal version. Clear cache and test.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to clean URLs, While moving Drupal website from one environment to other you need to check following things.

1. Apache rewrite module is enabled or not, it should be enabled.
2. In your Apache configuration check following

      AllowOverride All
3. You can also do this setting in .htaccess

Check following link for more details.

https://drupal.org/node/15365