# One time log in sent via email in drupal registration

Tags: drupal

I have a website 91.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite, i edited in sites-enabled so that when the user typed www.mywebsite.com it will redirect to

`91.xx.xx.xx/website`.

now my problem is when the user registers using the signup process of drupal, the email verification sent is still

`91.xx.xx.xx/verification url`,

(it is the one time log in url of drupal), and one more thing, whenever i clicked a link in the my site, the url doesnt change, it is still

`www.mywebsite.com`

example, im at

`www.mywebsite.com`

i click the link News, the url should now be,

`www.website.com/news`,

but the url still them, it doesnt change, but it goes to the correct page but the url is the same..

sorry for the long post but i would like to ask if anyone ever experienced this and wouldn't you mind sharing how did you manage to fix this, it'll be a great help.

thank you very much.

please free to ask if you need more information.

Comment: Could you paste the virtual host configuration?

Comment: thank you for the interest. do you mean the one i put in the site-available then enabled it using `a2ensite`?

Comment: `<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com *.mysite.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com *.mysite.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions inherit
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
`

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.php file within your Drupal site you should set the base_url variable. See [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879190/how-to-set-the-base-url-in-drupal).

```
$base_url = 'http://www.mywebsite.com';
```

Comment: i did that already but the website doesn't load anymore, i mean it just displays text...